# Access column name in a loop using GridViewRowEventArgs

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` which on data bound adds hyperlink to all the values in the `DataTable`. It is being achieved by using "GridViewRowEventArgs" functionality. But here I have to use the column names in the loop and i am unable to do it. Please help me with this.

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: "column names" here indicates column names of `DataTable` which you are binding to `GridView`?

Comment: @Bharadwaj: i guess he means the `HeaderText` of the column in the grid. The datasource is a bad choice since it's null on postback.

Comment: @TimSchmelter But, still we can access `DataTable` columns though `DataRowView` which we can get from `DataItem` property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Bharadwaj: which is `null` on postback ;)  Don't get me wrong, in `RowDataBound` the DataSource is always available, but if you want to use that method somewhere else(f.e. a button-click event handler), you cannot use it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter not on `RowDataBound` ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter: true, it can't be accessed on postback, can be used only on `RowDataBound`, or else it will be null.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this extension:

```
public static int GetColumnIndex(this GridView grid, string columnName)
{
    return grid.Columns.Cast<DataControlField>()
        .Select((c, index) => new { Column = c, Index = index })
        .Where(x => x.Column.HeaderText.Equals(columnName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        .Select(x => x.Index)
        .DefaultIfEmpty(-1)
        .First();
}
```

Then you can use it in this way:

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        GridView grid = (GridView)sender;
        int indexOfColumn = grid.GetColumnIndex("ColumnName");
        // for example to access the correct index in e.Row.Cells
        e.Row.Cells[indexOfColumn].Text = "Hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx for the comments:)

Comment: So is my answer not helpful? Is your issue solved? If so and the answer has  helped you might consider to accept it. You are welcome.